# With any function, sum all the values up to $f(n)$.

Tags: functions

Say you have the function: $y = x^{n}$ where $x$ is a Natural Number. Is there a simpler way to get the sum of $y_0, y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$ without having to calculate $y$ for every $n$?

If not, are there cases where with certain rules we can do so?

Comment: Please define your problem more clearly.  What is y0?  What is y1? etc

Comment: Try Googling geometric sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you want to calculate
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k.$$
This is a geometric sequence. The general formula for a GS is
$$\sum_{k=m}^{n}ax^k=\frac{a(x^m-x^{n+1})}{1-x},$$
where $r\neq1$. If $r=1$ then the GS is $a(n-m+1)$. So in your example we have $a=1$ and $m=0$. If $x\neq1$, the solution is
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+... = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$
and if $x=1$ this sequence obviously is equal to $n+1$.

Comment: Yup, this is it! Unfortunately it's too slow to run on my PC for large values.

Answer (score 1):

To get an estimate,
approximate the sum
by the integral:

$\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)
\approx \int_0^n f(x) dx
$.

To make this more rigorous,
you can use,
if $f(x)$ is increasing,
$f(n) \le \int_n^{n+1} f(x) dx
\le f(n+1)$
(with the reverse inequality
if $f(x)$ is decreasing)
and sum these terms.

This may eventually
lead to the Euler-Maclaurin
sum/integration formula.